# Why is my query checking 1000's of rows even though the table is indexed?

Tags: mysql

The table has around 20K rows and the following create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `inventory` (
      `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `TID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
      PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
      KEY `index_TID_CID_value` (`TID`,`CID`,`value`(25))
    );
```

and this is the result of the explain query

```
mysql> explain select rowID from inventory where TID=4 and CID=28 and value=3290843588097;
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys          | key                   | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inventory  | ref  | index_TID_CID_value    | index_TID_CID_value   | 10      | const,const | 9181 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The combination of TID=4 and CID=28 has around 13K rows in the table.

My questions are:

1. Why is the explain result telling me that around 9k rows will be
   examined to get the final result?
2. Why is the column `ref` showing only `const,const` since 3 columns are included in the multi column index shouldn't `ref` be `const,const,const` ?

**Update 7 Oct 2016**

Query:

```
select rowID from inventory where TID=4 and CID=28 and value=3290843588097;
```

I ran it about 10 times and took the times of the last five (they were the same)

- No index - 0.02 seconds
- Index (TID, CID) - 0.03 seconds
- Index (TID, CID, value) - 0.00 seconds

Also the same explain query looks different today, **how??** note the key len has changed to `88` and the ref has changed to `const,const,const` also the rows to examine have reduced to `2`.

```
mysql> explain select rowID from inventory where TID=4 and CID=28 and value='3290843588097';
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys        | key                 | key_len | ref               | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | inventory | ref  | index_TID_CID_value  | index_TID_CID_value | 88      | const,const,const |    2 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+-------------------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

Comment: How many combinations of TID, CID, value are in the table?

Comment: imo, not a lot of point in using indexes for that query - will be faster to just scan the one table? Have you used: `mysql analyze table` - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/analyze-table.html. i.e. how selective are those indexes?

Comment: @Mackers 1 combination

Comment: @RyanVincent could you elaborate why not to use indexes? What is a table scan? Haven't yet done the `mysql analyze table`

Comment: select count(*) from (select tid, cid, value from inventory group by tid, cid, value) a; What do you get from this query

Comment: @Mackers err 1248 every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @RyanVincent huh? and I thought indexes were meant to speed up searches? And how to read data in large blocks would it be as simple as a `SELECT` statement

Comment: @MiguelSanchez make sure the "a" is at the end of the query after the parentheses. That is the alias for the derived table.

Also, if tid,cid, and value make up a unique combination in a table, then you don't get much benefit from the index. If the index only has tid, and cid, then the index may help improve performance.

Comment: @Mackers it gives a result of around 17K

Comment: Sorry, just disable the use of the indexes and try the query again. Is it quicker. Indexes are like all features - useful when they are used in appropriate circumstances. And yes, they are very often are useful for 'web access' where the number of rows returned is `small`. So, indexes are essential.

Comment: Can you run this one as well? select count(*) from inventory where TID=4 and CID=28 and value=3290843588097;

Comment: @Mackers  the result is `2`

Comment: One final one:
 
select count(*) from (select tid, cid from inventory group by tid, cid) a;

Comment: @RyanVincent with index - `0.03s` without index - `0.02s` I don't know how to get accurate times but these are the results shown in mysql console

Comment: @Mackers the result is `2`

Comment: I lied, one more:
select count(*) from inventory where TID=4 and CID=28;

Comment: @RyanVincent I am currently just testing with a subset of the data the final data would probably close to 100K rows. So you are saying create 2 indexes 1 for `TID`, `CID` and another for `value`?

Comment: @Mackers around `13K` is the result

Comment: @RyanVincent ok! got it! so no index is also ok in this case since there isn't any speed benefit so to speak!

Comment: I do think that all the points that have been discussed will be useful to you in the future - especially with large tables and selectivity of indexes. Was enjoyable talking with you :)

Comment: @RyanVincent I equally enjoyed the discussion and your point of views on indices and mysql in general. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanVincent nice link! Why would the query get everything from the index when I have used `select rowID...` in the query and it would get that only in the main table. Another issue that troubles me is why is the `explain` query showing so much variation between yesterday's run and today's.

Answer (score 0):

To explicitly answer your questions.

1. The explain plan is giving you ~9k rows queried due to the fact that the engine needs to search through the index tree to find the row IDs that match your where-clause criteria. The index is going to produce a mapping of each possible combination of the index column values to a list of the rowIDs associated with that combination. In effect, the engine is searching those combinations to find the right one; this is done by scanning the combination, hence the ~9k amount.
2. Since your where-clause criteria involves all three of the index columns, the engine is optimizing the search by leveraging the index for the first two columns, and then short-circuiting the third column and getting all rowID results for that combination.

In your specific use-case, I'm assuming you want to optimize performance of the search. I would recommend that you create just an index on TID and CID (not value). The reason for this is that you currently only have 2 combinations of these values out of ~20k records. This means that using an index with just 2 columns, the engine will be able to almost immediately cut out half of the records when doing a search on all three values. (This is all assuming that this index will be applied to a table with a much larger dataset.) Since your metrics are based off a smaller dataset, you may not be seeing the order of magnitude of performance differences between using the index and not.

Comment: Would 100K rows be considered a large dataset to use an index?

Comment: It seems that if I include all 3 columns in the index it takes the least time, kindly see my updated question for new tests, do you still feel that I should only index TID and CID?